# "no even a" vs "not even a"

Tags: phrase-usage

What is the difference between *no even a* and *not even a*?
Are they both interchangeable and equally correct?
[EXAMPLES]:

- There is not even a single pen.
- There is no even a single pen.
- I have not even a single pen.
- I have no even a single pen.

Comment: Did you find "no even" used somewhere this way?

Comment: @user3169 Yes, I searched on Google and found a number of results having "no even a".

Comment: Please add a couple of such quotes to your question. I suspect that it is a conjunction of two phrases, such as "I have to say *no, even* if..." (with or without the comma).

Comment: All the results I found in a quick search were either probable typos or written by people who aren't native English speakers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing two phrases:

- There is **no** pen.
- There is a single pen. -> There is **not** a single pen. -> There is **not even** a single pen.

Basically both sentences express the absence of something, the latter having a  stonger emphasis.

But you can't write: <del>There is no even a single pen.</del>

Answer (score 1):

"Not even a" is correct. In some English dialects, speakers will drop the t and say "No even a single one." as a form of slang, but this is not correct.